# I cannot send primary key of one table to another as foreign key?

Tags: php, json

I am trying to get the id of the table province to insert it in the table city as foreign key but there is problem in my code, i cant the id to insert it in the city table as FK. this is the code.

```
<?php
 include 'connection.php';
 $result=mysqli_query ($conn,"set character_set_results='utf8'"); 
 $province_name=$_POST["province_name"];
 $city_name = $_POST["city_name"];
 $street = $_POST["street"];


    //$id=$_POST["id"];

   $result = mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO province (province_name) VALUES ('$province_name')");
   $id=$_POST["province_id"];

   $id= mysql_insert_id($conn);
   mysql_free_result( $result );
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO city (pidfk,city_name, street) VALUES ('$id','$city_name','$street')");



    $res=array();
    //$res['check']=false;
   if(mysqli_multi_query($conn,$result))
     {
        $res['check']=true;

     }

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($res);
 ?>
```

Comment: **Danger**: You are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that you need to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: yes but I now i just want to make this thing work

Comment: check my answer below @ArifMuhammad

Comment: I did but its not working, it gives error that  $id=$_POST["province_id"]; is not defined.. what to do?

Comment: @ArifMuhammad — Put it in the form?

Comment: i check it with postman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `mysql_insert_id` while you are using `mysqli`. You cant use both

change  `mysql_insert_id` to `mysqli_insert_id`